# Using Collector with ArcGIS for Personal Use

Tags: arcgis-collector, arcgis-personal-use

If I buy a personal use account will I be able to use collector to collect data in the field?

For context, I would like to be able to collect data points in the field to make my own hiking and trail maps.

If I will not be able to use collector, what would the community suggest?

Comment: One ArcGIS-desktop license = one named user in ArcGIS-online and Collector. But this is really a question you should ask Esri.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you are able to use Collector with a free account. There are a lot of limitations with the free account. I have used the app GIS Cloud Mobile Data Collection many times, but there is one problem that I came across. Unfortunately, with GIS Cloud Mobile Data Collection you cannot draw line features, and with hiking trails that is a crucial function. I have actually used it for a number of my hikes, and it works well for plotting points and taking pictures. I have an Iphone so this was my best option off of the App Store, but this app is also available on Google Play.

If you have an Android the best data collection app is MapIt GIS - GPS Data Collector and this app has the capabilities to draw line features. My coworker and I worked on a campus mapping project and I used the GIS Cloud Mobile Data Collection app while he used MapIt GIS - GPS Data Collector, and I must say his was much better for field collection.

I would check both of them out and see which one you prefer if you have Android, but if you have an Iphone then I would go with GIS Cloud Mobile Data Collection. With GIS Cloud Mobile Data Collection, you can always go to the website and download your layers as shapefiles and customize them however you want through your free ArcGIS account.